# AngularJS ng-bind-html not rendering list tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have a simple HTML document, like...

```
<ol>
    <li><strong>Test 1</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Test 2</strong></li>
</ol>
```

...and I want to bind it to a `div` with `ng-bind-html`, but the HTML tag `<ol>` (or `<li>`) is not rendered.

The result I have is:

```
<strong>Test 1</strong>
<strong>Test 2</strong>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your css file?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use ng-bind-html, you need to include ngSanitize in your app declaration

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-bind-html="myText"></div>

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.myText = "<ol><li><strong>Test 1</strong></li><li><strong>Test 2</strong></li></ol>";
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

`ng-bind-html` directive does it all. For more info, please visit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <span ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("myCtrl",["$scope","$sce", function($scope,$sce) {
    $scope.html = '<ol><li><strong>Test 1</strong></li><li><strong>Test 2</strong></li></ol>';
    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
    }]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```